# set "position:fixed" cause flicker in IE,but well in chrome,firefox,safari

Tags: internet-explorer, scroll, fixed, flicker

When I want to fixed `thead` of a table while scrolling down, it flickered in IE11, but it played well in others.
Coz it only caused by 'position:fixed',here is just javascript code.

```
window.onload = function () {
        var tableHead = document.getElementById("tableHead");
        var tableBody = document.getElementById("tableBody");
        var wired = document.getElementById("wired");
        var divLeft = document.getElementById("divLeft");
        var divTop = document.getElementById("divTop");
        window.onscroll = function () {
            var scrollTop = 0;
            scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop;
            if (scrollTop > 22) {
                tableBody.style.display = "block";
                tableHead.style.marginTop = "-23px";
                tableHead.style.position = "fixed";
                tableHead.style.zIndex = "99999";
                divLeft.style.position = "";
            } else {
                tableHead.style.display = "block";
                tableHead.style.position = "";
                tableHead.style.zIndex = "0";
                tableHead.style.marginTop = "0";
                tableBody.style.display = "block";
            }
}
```

Comment: Please show some code and/or a jsfidle showing the problem.

Comment: I just added the javascript code,thx for ur help further.

Comment: I am facing the same problem...did you figure out how to fix this?